# How to put all elements at the bottom of a flex column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a chat in Angular, and I am currently creating the feed component. I need to display the messages at the bottom.

I have this HTML code:

```
    <div class="feed">
 <div class="message">
   Test 1
 </div>
 <div class="message">
   Test 2
 </div> 
 <div class="message">
   Test 3
 </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.feed {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 1em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}

.message {
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

My problem is that the messages are displayed at the top. I have already tried to use "align-items", "align-sel", "justify-content", etc. 
This is what I get:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Comment: `justify-content:flex-end` or margin-top:auto on the first element